# Logging handler namer annotations in mypy

Tags: python, logging, callable, mypy

I'm trying to annotate my logging module using mypy in Python 3, however, I'm having issues annotating the namer function:

```
import logging

def _namer(name: str) -> str:
    return name + '.gz'

def get_logger(file_name: str, level: str) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(file_name, backupCount=30, when='midnight')

    handler.namer = _namer
    return logger
```

When I run mypy, I get this error when I assign _namer to handler.namer:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type Callable[[str], str], variable has type "Optional[Callable[[str], None]]")
```

Any idea how I'm supposed annotate _namer so that mypy doesn't complain about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug in mypy! Or more accurately, this is a bug in [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), a compendium of type stubs for various libraries used by different type checkers, including mypy.

After looking through the documentation and the [source code of logging.handler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L77), it does seem that the type of the `handler.namer` attribute should be `Optional[Callable[[str], str]]`, which matches your code.

However, if we [check typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/logging/handlers.pyi#L31), we can see it's given a type of `Optional[Callable[[str], None]]`. This seems like a simple oversight to me.

I would recommend making pull request with a fix at the typeshed repo. Until then, you can silence mypy by adding the `# type: ignore` comment to that line with the assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will try to ignore this for now. I will also take a look at Typeshed codebase to see where I need to change.

Comment: @mohi666 -- I believe the third link in my answer should point you to the class you probably want to change; I'd start there.

Comment: They merged the fix. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/1498